# How I declare Textview variable

Tags: java, android, textview

My question is how I declare Textview variable in javacode?

My code is here:

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
```

i want using tv1 in this function:

```
build.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

}
```

I try this code : `tv1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this)` but i had this issue:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error on token "new", delete this token
>     - TextView cannot be resolved to a variable
>     - The final local variable tv1 cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an     enclosing type

Comment: You must find the TextView in your Layout. Something like `final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you lack the very minimal knowledge of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findViewById().. does it ring a bell?

You need to declare the Text view in the content view layout and use the same, by assigning it using findViewById(R.id.view_id );

For adding textview to layout follow this

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout2);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Text here");
tv.setId(id);
linear.addView(tv);
```

Comment: Sorry @Der I didn't check the comment earlier.

Comment: @furkan have edited my answer to add textview from code this may help you